# Azure Keyvault Bad Request When Called From Kubernetes Pod

Tags: azure, authentication, kubernetes, azure-keyvault, azure-aks

I've run into a problem accessing Azure Key Vault whilst converting some services from Microsoft Service Fabric to Kubernetes. Within our ASP.NET core ConfigureServices call, we call AddAzureKeyVault from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationExtensions to inject some sensitive parts of our configuration as shown below.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddAzureKeyVault(
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_LOCATION"),
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_CLIENT_ID"),
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_CLIENT_SECRET")
        ).Build();

        //...
}
```

This works fine in a docker image running locally, yet once deployed into Azure Kubernetes service the pod is failing with the following...

```
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Looking at the source of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationExtensions I can reproduce the issue with this minimal code.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    GetSecrets(
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_LOCATION"),
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_CLIENT_ID"),
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_CLIENT_SECRET")
    ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public async Task GetSecrets(string loc, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback callback =
        (authority, resource, scope) => GetTokenFromClientSecret(authority, resource, clientId, clientSecret);

    IKeyVaultClient _client = new KeyVaultClient(callback);

    //Exception thrown here
    var secrets = await _client.GetSecretsAsync(loc).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private static async Task<string> GetTokenFromClientSecret(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

My question is, what is different about this authentication when called from within a pod in AKS, as opposed to a local docker image, that would lead this call to fail?

I've confirmed the pod can access the wider internet, the key vault is not firewalled and Insights is showing some Authentication failures in the key vault logs. The Client Id and Secret are correct and have the correct rights since this works locally in Docker. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the environment variables in the pod definition correctly?

Comment: Did you assign the "Reader" role to the service principal? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-integrate-kubernetes#assign-a-service-principal

Comment: @Faheem Initially they were coming in via a secret, but I've tried including them in the docker image itself instead to isolate that as a source of errors. Unfornately have the same result (works locally, not in kubernetes) so yes I'm sure they're right.

Comment: @AllenWu I'd looked at the secret store approach, but hoped our existing AzureKeyVaultConfigurationExtensions approach would work. That remains a fallback.

The App Registration associated with the client id and secret does have Get and List rights via access policies, I've granted it Reader too but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Can you capture the response code and detailed error message?

Comment: KeyVaultClient is being deprecated in favor of SecretClient, available in our new package, Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets. We also split KeyClient and CertificateClient into separate packages. See https://aka.ms/valueprop and https://aka.ms/intro for more information. Used with DefaultAzureCredential from Azure.Identity, these are easier to use and do not require code changes from development to production environments.

Comment: This was from the internals of the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationExtensions package. Will this be updated / replaced with the new approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code sample on my machine, local cluster, and an AKS cluster. It's working in all places. Please check your environment. You may be looking in the wrong place. There must be something in your local environment. Try running it in a different environment. For example: from home (without VPN).

Comment: I eventually got back to this and found the issue. It turns out you're quite right. I had a duplicate deployment manifest that continued to apply the secrets, overwriting the local values I had baked in. After installing lens and looking at the secrets I discovered whilst they appear correct they all contained a trailing newline.